# In playwright asserting for the existence of a text in a element

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

There is an element that loads up after a few seconds the form is submitted(page doesn't reload after submission). I want to assert that this element has some text value in it. Value doesn't matter but there should be some text in the element.

Currently I am asserting it like this -

```
await expect(await targetPage.locatorToSomeElement.innerText()).toBeTruthy();
```

OR this -

```
await expect(targetPage.locatorToSomeElement).toBeTruthy();
```

`targetPage`is class instance of Page Object Model class `TargetPage` and
`locatorToSomeElement` is locator with value `page.getByTestId("some-span-element")`;

Please let me know the best way to achieve this. Please check below points as well.

1. The first statement seems like a manual assertion? await is inside expect? It's a bad practice? https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions
2. `toBeTruthy()` is an assertion that doesn't not auto wait so I believe second statement will always be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct--you need to use web-first assertions to ensure auto-waiting.

How about:

```js
await expect(targetPage.locatorToSomeElement).toHaveText(/\S/);
```

The regex here means "contains at least one non-space character".

Complete, runnable example:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test("h1 is eventually not empty", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(`<h1></h1><script>
    setTimeout(() =>
      document.querySelector("h1").textContent = "ok",
      2000
    )</script>
  `);
  await expect(page.locator("h1")).toHaveText(/\S/);
});

test("h1 is eventually empty", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(`<h1>test</h1><script>
    setTimeout(() =>
      document.querySelector("h1").textContent = "   ",
      2000
    )</script>
  `);
  await expect(page.locator("h1")).not.toHaveText(/\S/);
  await expect(page.locator("h1")).toHaveText(/^\s*$/);
});

test("multiple paragraphs have text", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(`<p>a</p><p>b</p>`);
  await expect(page.locator("p")).toHaveText([/\S/, /\S/]);
});
```

I'm not sure what your use case is, but you may want to strengthen the assertion further. For example, `.toHaveText(/.{42,}/)` ensures there are at least 42 characters present.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `toHaveText` with complex regex , you can simply use `toContainText` in places where exact string is unknown.

**Note**:

> Unlike toHaveText [toContainText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-contain-text), when specified with the partial
> text, it will assert and confirm the element with its presence. You don't need to
> provide the exact text like toHaveText.

Ultimately both gives you an option to use regex to use them with flexibility.