Check if element contains any text
In my test case there is an element that should be checked if it contains any text and it's not empty, and if it's empty fail the test.
I've tried to use toHaveText without a string like so:
await expect(myLocator).toHaveText();

but passing string/regex is mandatory.
How can I assert this kind of thing?

"if it's empty fail the test" - /.+/?

@jonrsharpe I left this comment elsewhere, but be careful with /.+/ because it considers <p> </p> as nonempty. 99% of the time, I'd expect whitespace to be empty, so /\S/ seems preferable ("at least one non-whitespace character"). See this answer.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77006101/1831456

I've found a way using Regex "Dot" Metacharacter, which means Any character (except newline character):
await expect(myLocator).toHaveText(/./);


This will match elements with a single whitespace, which I'd usually expect would be empty. /\S/ might be more desirable in the common case. See this answer.

You could use the following to check if the element has any text in it:
expect(locator).not.toBeEmpty();

As found in the playwright documentation (
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-empty):

toBeEmpty
Ensures the Locator points to an empty editable element or to a DOM
node that has no text.

